# Spring DefaultListableBeanFactory Memory Leak in conjunction with @DirtiesContext

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

Due to the fact that we are using de.flapdoodle embedded mongoDB for our integration tests with maven failsave plugin. We are getting an OutOfMemoryException when running multiple tests at once.

The heap space is limited by -Xmx256m
Increasing it to 1G for the failsave plugin eliminates (postpones) this problem.

I created a heap dump with -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError and analyzed it with eclipse mat. It seems that DefaultListableBeanFactory is the top consumer.

[image]

Running a single test is not an issue, but it seems to accumulate over multiple test cases.

Some of our integration tests are annotated with the following annotations:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
```

How do those both relate to each other?
Is my assumption right that the DefaultListableBeanFactory instances are singleton instances possibly from multiple test cases and not garbage collected?

Comment: Each test configuration combination (and a few more things) uniquely will define a key for a cached application context (by default the test context framework caches 32 of them). So if you have a lot of integration tests with `@MockBean` or deducted test listeners, overridden properties it will create a new applicationcontext and add it to the cache. So yes you will have multiple instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html

I thought that DirtiesContext will mark the context as dirty: 
" should therefore be closed and removed from the context cache. "

Is it a bug that it still remains within the cache?

If not: What is a sensible size for the heap for integration tests, when the context cache of the test framework can grow to up to 32 instances of the application context?

Comment: What size you need depends on your needs. If you set it to 1 nothing will be cached basically, however this will impact performance of your tests. On the other hand if you use a lot of `@MOckBean` or other changes in your contexts you might have to reconsider those integration tests and write plain unit tests instead, `@DirtiesContext` refreshes the application context it doesn't remove it from the cache.